# Panel в Scroll View

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Я делаю что-то вроде блокнота.Проблема в том что добавляя какой-то объект в panel в scroll view он становится в конце panel.И я обнаружил,что если перенести в иерархии в эдиторе объект, то он поменяет своё положение и в panel.Вопрос: как менять порядок объектов в иерархии через код?Или есть ли другое нормальное решение?

Answer (score 0):

За изменение порядка в иерархии отвечает функция **Transform.SetSiblingIndex**.

Изменение будет происходить только в родителе, там где находится объект.

---

### Сделать объект первым

```
transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
```

или

```
transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
```

### Сделать объект последним

```
transform.SetAsLastSibling();
```

### Получить индекс

```
transform.GetSiblingIndex();
```